# How to share the x-axis in these stack plots

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, spyder, subplot

I am trying to share the have the same x-axis for these two plots, but the sharex=true is not working as I thought it would.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5),sharex=True)
ax = plt.subplot(211)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air1', data = df, label = 'Temp °C') 
ax = plt.subplot(212)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air2', data = df, label = 'Temp °C')
```

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RAdd.png)

Comment: Show atleast what image you've got

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, done! (sorry about the missing image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code?

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air1', data = df, label = 'Temp °C') 
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air2', data = df, label = 'Temp °C') 
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
```

I don't know your data but i tried it with my own created data and i got this output, please give feedback if it's wrong.
[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.
Just a couple of thigs to improve:

" fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air1', data = df, label = 'Temp °C')
ax1.set(xlabel =None)
ax1.tick_params(bottom=False)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
sns.lineplot(x ='Date', y = 'Air2', data = df, label = 'Temp °C') 
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])"

Comment: @MonicaPena Yes, i already edited the code.